# Why can't I return map of previous state when using React useReducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I've created a simple app to illustrate:

- Broken: https://codesandbox.io/s/reducer-nightmare-5zxkw
- Working: https://codesandbox.io/s/reducer-nightmare-soloution-hm6r6

In the app I'm using a reducer to keep state of and array of check boxes and a allChecked boolean

```
{
  checks: [
    { id: 1, selected: false },
    { id: 2, selected: false },
    { id: 3, selected: false },
  ],
  allChecked: false,
}
```

I have a reducer that when one checkbox is changed, should identify that checkbox in the array of checks and set the value to the opposite of what it was

```
  case 'SELECT_CHECK': {
    return {
      checks: state.checks.map((check, i) => {
        if (action.id === check.id) {
          check.selected = !check.selected;
        }
        return check;
      }),
      allChecked: state.checks.reduce((acc, check) => {
        if (!acc) return false;
        return check.selected;
      }, true),
    };
  }
```

When each checkbox is clicked the map should run and return `check.selected = !check.selected`. logging this out shows that it works as intended but retuning this state never changes the state. and the checkbox never gets checked.

I've found a work around which is passing the state of the checkbox with the dispatch action, and explicitly setting the new state of the checkbox to the `e.target.checked`

```
  //checkbox jsx
  <input
    type='checkbox'
    checked={check.selected}
    onChange={(e) => {
      dispatch({ type: 'SELECT_CHECK', id: check.id, checked: e.target.checked });
    }}
  />
  //reducer case statement
  case 'SELECT_CHECK': {
    return {
      checks: state.checks.map((check, i) => {
        if (action.id === check.id) {
          check.selected = action.checked;
        }
        return check;
      }),
      allChecked: state.checks.reduce((acc, check) => {
        if (!acc) return false;
        return check.selected;
      }, true),
    };
  }
```

While this functions I would like to understand why the initial attempt doesn't work and if there is a way to make this function sans passing the `action.checked` value.

Here is a GIF to show the expected State
[Select All Checkbox Demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONMFE.gif)

Comment: You're mutating the state. Never do that in React

Comment: Thanks @CertainPerformance! I thought that .map returned a copy of state. I also tried `[...state.checks]` to get a copy to no avail. Is there a proper way to do this without passing the `action.checked`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you need to update an object in React state, you should always *replace the existing object* in state with the new object instead of mutating the object in state. This:

```
  checks: state.checks.map((check, i) => {
    if (action.id === check.id) {
      check.selected = !check.selected;
    }
    return check;
  }),
```

should be

```
  checks: state.checks.map(check => (
    action.id === check.id ? ({ ...check, selected: !check.selected }) : check
  ))
```

The

```
{ ...check, selected: !check.selected }
```

creates a new object with all the properties of the existing object in state, except with an inverted `selected` property.

In contrast, your

```
check.selected = !check.selected;
```

mutates the object without returning a new one, and in such a case - if the object in the previous state and the object in the new state are `===` - React may try to completely skip the re-rendering involving that object, because it doesn't detect a state difference.

Comment: Thanks so much! I didn't understand that by returning `check` instead of `{...check}` i was mutating state I assumed that .map was copying. I also found this which helped explain further: https://jkettmann.com/how-to-accidentally-mutate-state-and-why-not-to